# A-paths on Lie algebroids?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-algebroids

In the paper **integrability of Lie brackets** M. Crainic and L. R. Fernandez define the notion of A-path as follows.

**Definition.** Let $A\stackrel{\pi}{\longrightarrow} M$ be a Lie algebroid. An **A-path** is a $C^1$ curve $a:I\longrightarrow A$ such that $$\sharp a(t)=\frac{d}{dt} \pi(a(t)),$$ where $\sharp:A\longrightarrow TM$ is the anchor map.

I'm trying to make sense of this definition. What does $\frac{d}{dt}\pi(a(t))$ mean? I don't understand for it should be a map from $I$ to $TM$.

Thanks.

Comment: $TI \cong I \times I \hookrightarrow TM$, so just restrict to the fiber over $t$ and applies $\partial_t$. This is just differentiation of a curve on a manifold

Comment: This means that you have a curve on $M$ and on $A$ that are compatible in the sense that the vector field of tangent vectors to the curve in $TM$ is the anchor applied to the curve on $A$

Comment: Do you mean I must use the embedding $I\hookrightarrow TI$?

Comment: Not exactly. You just apply the vector field $\partial_t $ to $Da : TI \rightarrow TA$.

Comment: Ops! I mean $D(\pi \circ a) : TI \rightarrow TA$.

Comment: Sorry but I still don't understand. How do you start from $I$ and arrive on $TM$ using your approach?

Comment: If you have a vector field $X$ in $M$ and a function $f: TM \rightarrow TN$, what's the domain of $f (X)$?

Comment: Well, $I\stackrel{\partial_t}{\longrightarrow} TI$ and $TI\stackrel{Da}{\longrightarrow} TA$ so I still can't see how to get a map $I\longrightarrow TM$?

Comment: $D (\pi \circ  a) : TI \rightarrow TM$.

Comment: Briefly, do you mean $\frac{d}{dt}\pi(a(t))=(\pi(a(t)), (\pi\circ a)^\prime(t))$ ?(for me for a manifold $X$ $TX=\{(p, X): p\in X, X\in T_p X\}$).

Comment: Yes, this holds locally.